# Matching strings to arrays

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with this code:

```
var buyerChoice = prompt("Enter a either apple, orange, or banana:", "");        

var fruits = new Array ("apple", "orange", "banana");

for(i=0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
    if(buyerChoice === fruits[i]) {
        document.write(buyerChoice);
    } else if (buyerChoice !== fruits[i]){
        document.write("Sorry, " +buyerChoice+ " is out of season.");
        break;
    }
}
```

I believe the problems lies in the `else-if` statement because every time I type in an item that exists in my variable, it will return `//appleSorry, apple is out of season`, thus meeting both conditions.

I'm stumped. I guess the bottom line is how to effectively match a string from a prompt to an array, testing each item and how to parse an array if a prompted string doesn't exist.

Comment: I believe `items` is not defined

Comment: @Dave: Perhaps you mean `var fruits = ["apple", "orange", "banana"];`?

Comment: sorry, that should read fruits[i] ... it was because i ctrl-z my way back to this first problem which i already troubleshooted. good eye.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var buyerChoice = prompt("Enter a either apple, orange, or banana:", "");        

var fruits = ["apple", "orange", "banana"];

var outOfSeason = false;
for(fruit in fruits) {
    if(buyerChoice === fruits[fruit]) {
        matched = true;
        break;
    }
}

if(! outOfSeason){
   document.write(buyerChoice);
}
else{
   document.write("Sorry, " +buyerChoice+ " is out of season.");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the first iteration, the entered fruit either is or is not equal to "apple". But if it isn't "apple" the first iteration (but e.g. "orange"), then that does not mean "orange" is not available at all.

You should keep track whether you've matched anything (through using a variable), and only if *after the loop* nothing has been matched, then the entered fruit is indeed not available.

Answer (score 1):

your for-loop isn't logical at all. Therefore `items` wont work if it's undefined.

here's a possible solution

```
var outofseason = true;
for(i=0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
    if(buyerChoice === fruits[i]) {
        outofseason = false;
        break;
    }
}

if ( outofseason ) {
    document.write("Sorry, " +buyerChoice+ " is out of season.");
}
else {
    document.write(buyerChoice);
}
```

Comment: that was my fault. i ctrl-z'ed my way back to this first problem which i already troubleshooted. good eye! thanks for this code. i'll study it, kinda new jargon for me. thanks a lot!

Comment: It checks! Thanks a lot. It laid out the blueprint for the while loop i've been trying to solve for the rock/paper/scissors game ... that would validate user entry if its other those three items.

Answer (score 1):

```
// let the fruits be a global var instead of recreating it every time you call the function below
var fruits = ["apple", "orange", "banana"];

function askBuyerForFruit() {
  var buyerChoice = prompt("Enter a either apple, orange, or banana:", "");

  for (var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
    if (fruits[i] === buyerChoice) {
      document.write(buyerChoice);
      // get out of the function if found;
      return;
    }
  }

  // fallback if no matching fruit found
  document.write("Sorry, " +buyerChoice+ " is out of season.");
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure what the for loop is trying to accomplish but you could use `indexOf`

```
var buyerChoice = prompt("Enter a either apple, orange, or banana:", "");
var fruits = new Array ("apple", "orange", "banana");

var matchedIndex = fruits.indexOf(buyerChoice);

if (matchedIndex < 0) { //did not match
    document.write("Sorry, " +buyerChoice+ " is out of season.");
} else {
    document.write(buyerChoice)
}
```

Comment: this could also do the trick and the code is formed more neatly.

Answer (score 0):

change items[i] to fruits[i] this will solve your problem

Comment: this won't help with the logical problems,
please also format code parts correct, thx